как разделить имена по двум последним буквам в CSV-файле?
как отсортировать имена по двум последним буквам в CSV-файле?
например, у меня есть файл csv и мне нужно отсортировать имена по последним двум буквам например (ас,ис)и выбрать стас и борис и сохранить их в другой файл csv
index,name 
1,Sitor
2,Стас
3,Soliham
4,Борис   


Ну, читаете csv файл, проходитесь по строкам, делаете срез без последних двух символов, записываете в файл. В чём трудности возникли?

Формулировка не очень понятная, нужно приводить в вопросе и желаемый результат. А так то задача элементарная с виду. Ну и да - вы даже не попытались ничего сами сделать, это здесь не приветствуется.

Например ввести ключевое слова (ис) и выбрать борис

Хм, это вообще-то другая задача, чем та, которую вы описали в вопросе. А так то что сложного - читаете файл и через in проверяете наличие подстроки в строке.

Можете показать это мне в виде кода?
